# Changing A Windows 10 Account Name With A Batch File

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file, cmd.exe

I've been looking around and can't find an answer to this.

i want to change an account name with a batch file

Answer (score 3):

In an elevated command prompt run the following:

`wmic useraccount where name='currentname' rename newname`

`currentname` will be what it currently is

`newname` is what you want it to be.

e.g.

`wmic useraccount where name='JigglePiggle' rename JP`

Comment: As Microsoft [says](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2454362/renaming-a-user-account-does-not-automatically-change-the-profile-path) : "When you rename a user account [...], the user profile path is not changed automatically. It may cause some confusion when the `%SystemDrive%\users` folder is viewed".